# How to route to another modules component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have two modules: `app.module.ts` and `auth.module.ts`. The `auth.module.ts` has two components: `login.components.ts` and `registration.component.ts`.

I want the `login.components.ts` to handle the route `www.mywebsite.com/login` and the `registration.component.ts` handle the route `www.mywebsite.com/registration`.

If I use lazy loading routing

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('../auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
```

**auth-routing.module.ts**

```
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
```

then the path becomes `www.mywebsite.com/login/login`.

How do I make `www.mywebsite.com/login` to be handled by `login.component.ts` from `auth.module.ts` and `www.mywebsite.com/registration` handled by `registration.component.ts` from `auth.module.ts`?

[StackBlits project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsvqzz)

### Side note:

I also tried to use `LoginComopnent` from `auth.module.ts` directly in `app-routing.module.ts`

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { LoginComponent } from '../auth/login/login.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
];
```

but this resulted in `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.` error, even tough I had `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` imported in both `app.module.ts` and `auth.moduel.ts` modules.

Comment: You’re using reactive form not template forms so you only need to import ReactiveFormsModule and only in AuthModule.  You’ll get errors if you don’t have matching form controls in the template I.e. formControlName=“user” etc

Comment: Removing FormModule from both modules and leaving only ReactiveModule in `auth.module.ts` didn't help. Still the same error appears. Checkout the StackBlitz project I linked in the question, pls. @AndrewAllen

Comment: I did look at the Stackblitz when I commented. *You don’t have matching form controls in the template*

Comment: I have to admit, I'm lost. Can you fix it for me, please? @AndrewAllen
My code matches the one from [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls)

Comment: Sorry, don’t code for free :) suggest working through new docs https://angular.dev/ or old docs tour of heroes

Comment: There's literally ~1 min of code :D I worked through "tour of heroes" and bunch of other tutorials and courses. I'm just wondering if you will be able to fix it in practice. @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 1):

Think about this if you didn't have modules.  If you had a parent route you wouldn't make the child routes have the same name

```
 {
  path: 'login',
  children: [
     {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

Of course that would result in a `/login/login` route. Instead you would leave one unnamed, like this:

```
 {
  path: 'login',
  children: [
     {
      path: '',
      component: LoginComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

that results in `/login`.

So for your case, with a nested module I think you'l have to give it a name. I recommend `auth`, like this

```
{
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('../auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
```

And then you have the `auth/login` and `auth/registration` routes

See [a StackBlitz of this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbzydm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Yes, but then how do I know  which component to load, that is if it's `www.mywebsite.com/login` or `www.mywebsite.com/registration`? Both `LoginComponent` and `RegistrationComponent` are part of the `AuthModule`.

Comment: @FAMO4S See my updated answer with a different suggestion

Comment: The `auth` prefix. Yeah, my whole question was if it's possible to route to another module's component without adding another path segment (the `/auth``). I guess it means it's not doable.

Comment: You could possibly have `auth/` and then `auth/registration/` - meaning the first route would need to be an empty string. Not perfect but getting closer I suppose